# Order by is not using index, strange behaviour?

Tags: mysql

I experience some problems when I try to get some mysql data using where and order.

The order is not using the table index even if I use where or simply order.

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` 
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  KEY `price` (`price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

And I have this inserted rows, they are demo rows, number of rows it might get to 10.000

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id`, `title`, `price`) 
VALUES
    (1, 'pede. Praesent eu dui. Cum', 552),
    (2, 'lobortis tellus justo sit amet', 663),
    (3, 'Nulla tempor augue ac ipsum.', 87),
    (4, 'Ut sagittis lobortis mauris. Suspendisse', 653),
    (5, 'orci luctus et ultrices posuere', 88),
    (6, 'In at pede. Cras vulputate', 474),
    (7, 'erat eget ipsum. Suspendisse sagittis.', 686),
    (8, 'magna nec quam. Curabitur vel', 999),
    (9, 'felis eget varius ultrices, mauris', 23),
    (10, 'ut, pharetra sed, hendrerit a,', 943);
```

Here are my queries

```
Explain SELECT id,title,price FROM `myTable` order by price
```

is not using any index, is using filesort.

```
Explain SELECT price FROM `myTable` order by price
```

Is using the price index, but i need to get all my data, not only price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create covering index

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_price_title` ON myTable(price,title);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now see the `explain` plan, It is using the correct index

```
Explain SELECT id,title,price FROM `myTable` order by price;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key             | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myTable | index | NULL          | idx_price_title | 772     | NULL |   10 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the best! Any possible explication why my queries where not working right?

Comment: @DownVoters , Please at least post reason for down vote.